# Which is the best windows emulator for ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, windows, wine, games, emulation

I have wine installed on my system but is not able to run games like prince of persia the two thrones, Grandmaster (chess) properly. Hence, I'm looking for other options. Even with wine, is any changes in setting can improve the performance.

Comment: Anything else would most likely be wine based. You could look into virtualization (VMWare/Virtualbox) as an alternative. Have you looked in the AppDB for tips on how to get your application running better? https://appdb.winehq.org/

Comment: Try Play In Linux, it is a frontend for Wine, but makes its own configurations, for ease of use.

Comment: @amanthethy Didn't find the game I was looking on winehq. I'm gonna try virtualbox. Anyways, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Windows in [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), but you will have to buy a Windows license key, if you want to activate Windows. *Note: that you do not have to buy a licence key to use Windows.*

You can download an official ISO file for Windows 10 here, [Download Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10ISO)

Comment: I installed virtualbox but I'm not able to install windows 8.1 in it. Perhaps because it is 64 bit but it's only one whose license I have. Do you have any idea how to resolve it? I googled it but didn't get a very explaining answer.

Comment: Do you have a 64bit windows license, and you are running 32bit ubuntu? If so, I don't think you would be able to emulate windows with that license.

You could split your harddisk to two partitions, one with Windows

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 64 bit. Well, I solved the problem by properly configuring bumblebee and nvidia graphics. Games are running fine when I use the GPU, however still they don't run properly with the CPU. It isn't any issue. However I would like to know the process to install the 64 bit windows in  virtual box as it may come handy in future.

Comment: Can fully install Windows in Virtual Box using the USB backup/recovery drive?

Comment: @Ohm you can download an official ISO file for Windows 10 here [Download Windows ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10ISO), Then add the iso file to a Virtual Box image, as a disc.

Answer (score 2):

You can just run a partition with Windows installed as a second OS. It's not hard to do. I actually came from the other side, starting with Windows and partitioning to download Ubuntu 14.04